# why do network socket connect and send/recieve data takes long in wireless?

Tags: java, c#, android, windows, sockets

I made an app client in android device (with ethernet and wireless port) and server application in windows.

Data transfers via Socket programming between devices and when i test it in emulator in PC or run in Ethernet via cable it works correctly, but when i connect server and client with wireless connectivity (via an access point) data sent or received with a delay . this delay may be take over 60 seconds !

i don't know why this problem happend !

This is my sending routin in android :

```
 Server_Port = mDbHelper.GetPortNumber();
    //mDbHelper.close();

    final String Concatinate_values = firstByte_KindType + Spliter + secoundByte_KindofMove +
            Spliter + ValueOfMove + Spliter + valueOfsetting + Spliter + MaxOrMinValue;


    //Sent Routin
    ////‌Connect To server

    Thread thread = null;

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            BufferedReader inputStream = null;
            Socket socket;
            socket = new Socket();

            try {

                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Server_IP, Server_Port), 10);

            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            ////Make Read Line
            try {
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                //Finished Socket

                ShutDown(socket);
            }

            if (outputStream == null) {
                //
                ShutDown(socket);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }

            //Write Message
            try {
                String message = Concatinate_values + "\n";

                outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();

                ShutDown(socket);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

            }

            try {
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ShutDown(socket);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

My windows server code in c# :

```
class Program
{
    static Socket socketForClient;
    static NetworkStream networkStream;
    static System.IO.StreamReader streamReader;
    static System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter;
    static TcpListener tcpListener;
    static int PORT;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Console.WriteLine("Enter Port : ");
        //PORT = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PORT = 12500;

        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Your Host Information Is : "+"\n" );
        IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in localIPs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
        }
        while (true)
        {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(PORT);
        Console.WriteLine("\n >> Server started ... Waiting for Message");
        tcpListener.Start();

        try
        {
            socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LN: 40");
            Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e1.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + e1.InnerException);
            Console.WriteLine("Source: " + e1.Source);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        if (socketForClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            try
            {
                networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LN: 55");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e1.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + e1.InnerException);
                Console.WriteLine("Source: " + e1.Source);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            //System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
            try
            {
                streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
                 streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LN: 71");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e1.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + e1.InnerException);
                Console.WriteLine("Source: " + e1.Source);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            string theString = "Sending";
            // streamWriter.WriteLine(theString);
            Console.WriteLine(theString);
            //streamWriter.Flush();
            long x = 0;


                try
                {
                    x++;
                    theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    if (theString.Trim() == "4-")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending Report Data : 0-100-0-0");
                        streamWriter.WriteLine("0-70-0-0");
                        Console.WriteLine("pocket sent");
                        streamWriter.Flush();

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(theString + x.ToString());

                    streamReader.Close();
                    networkStream.Close();
                    socketForClient.Close();
                    tcpListener.Stop();



                }
                catch (System.Exception e1)
                {

                    streamReader.Close();
                    networkStream.Close();
                    socketForClient.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("LN: 97");
                    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e1.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + e1.InnerException);
                    Console.WriteLine("Source: " + e1.Source);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    break;
                    //streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }

        }

        streamReader.Close();
        networkStream.Close();
        socketForClient.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Closed Socket");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: If the delay is over 60 seconds it might be a failure/timeout. Does the correct data get sent after the delay?

Comment: yes data send after delay correctly . i think in making socket it has delay ! i will write my windows server in my post too see it .